# buildroot defconfig for pocketBeagle is not working

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot, buildroot

I have a pocketbeagle board and I was trying to build an os image for it using buildroot.
so I downloaded the latest buildroot, there was no *defconfig* file for pocketbeagle. so decided to use *beaglebone_defconfig*. The build was successful but when I try to boot the pocketbeagle with this image it is continuously printing this message on the uart console:

*Could not initialize timer (err -19)

Could not initialize timer (err -19)

Could not initialize timer (err -19)

Could not initialize timer (err -19)

Could not initialize timer (err -19)

Could not initialize timer (err -19)*

I think this message is coming from uboot.

This is the steps I used to build the image:

```
cd buildroot-2021.02.10
make beaglebone_defconfig
make
```

do I need to apply some patch? or is it because of some other issue? also tried with the buildroot available in beagleboard github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there are differences in the 2 boards. Your build would succeed but wont run on pocket beagle because it is not meant to run on it.

| specifications | pocket beagle | Beagle bone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SoC | OSD3358-SM | AM3358/9 |
| CPU | Sitara AM3358 M Cortex-A8 | Cortex-A8 + Dual PRU (200 MHz) |
| Frq (MHz) | 1000 | 720 |

To build BSP for pocket beagle follow below steps,

1. In Target options
   – Change Target architecture to ARM (little endian)
   – Change Target architecture variant to Cortex-A8
2. In Build options, set global patch directories to board/e-ale/pocketbeagle/patches/.
   This will allow you to put patches for Linux, U-Boot other packages in subdirectories of board/e-ale/pocketbeagle/patches/.
3. Toolchain - you can use external or internal.
4. In Kernel
   – Enable the Linux kernel, obviously!
   – Choose Custom version as the Kernel version
   – Choose 4.14.24 as Kernel version
   – Patches will already be applied to the kernel, thanks to us having defined a global patch directory above.
   – Choose omap2plus as the Defconfig name
   – We’ll need the Device Tree of the PocketBeagle, so enable Build a Device Tree Blob (DTB)
   – And use am335x-pocketbeagle as the Device Tree Source file names
5. Target packages - as per your requirement.
6. In Filesystem images, enable ext2/3/4 root filesystem, select the ext4 variant.
7. In Bootloaders, enable U-Boot, and in U-Boot:
   – Switch the Build system option to Kconfig: use U-Boot
   – Use a Custom version of value 2018.01.
   – Use am335x_pocketbeagle as the Board defconfig

As you have noticed, in the configuration, you have referenced board/e-ale/pocketbeagle/ patches as a directory containing patches for various packages. We now need to add the U-Boot and Linux patches that add support for the PocketBeagle, which are not upstream. Use [patches](https://github.com/e-ale/buildroot-e-ale/tree/master/board/pocketbeagle/patches), and just copy it to board/e-ale/pocketbeagle so that you get the following directory hierarchy:
[image: directory]

Then build the BSP and run on your device.

[source](https://bootlin.com/pub/conferences/2018/elce/petazzoni-buildroot-tutorial/petazzoni-buildroot-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: I found that all of the steps can be done just by downloading the e-ale buildroot source and then copying the "board/pocketbeagle/" directory contents and pocketbeagle_defconfig file to my buildroot directory. Now I can build it just fine. there are some errors when directly trying to build e-ale buildroot.